# Issues with BitmapData of a MovieClip with rotationY applied to it

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, rotation, bitmapdata

So I have a simple file right now that eventually will take a movieclip and save it as an image. I am currently rotating the clip's y by 45 to give it kind of a 3D look and adding it back to the stage. I've tried googling and a couple different things, but I can't quite get it to work. The first thing I tried was getting the BitmapData of the movieclip I rotated. That flattened the clip:

```
test_mc.response_mc.rotationY = 45;
var mc:MovieClip = test_mc.response_mc;
var bmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(mc.width, mc.height);
bmp.draw(mc);

var output:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmp);
output.x = 270;
output.y = 191;

addChild(output);
```

The next thing I tried was getting the parent clip's BD. That gave it an angle... just the wrong one:

```
(same code as above with this line change)
var mc:MovieClip = test_mc;
```

Any thoughts here would be nice. I tried doing stuff with matrices, but had no luck. I also have images... just can't post them yet :(

Something else I've tried with no luck:

```
var target:DisplayObject = test_mc as DisplayObject;
var targetTransform:Matrix = target.transform.concatenatedMatrix;
var targetGlobalBounds:Rectangle = target.getBounds(target.stage);
var targetGlobalPos:Point = target.localToGlobal(new Point());
var targetOriginOffset:Point = new Point(targetGlobalPos.x - targetGlobalBounds.left, targetGlobalPos.y - targetGlobalBounds.top);

targetTransform.tx = targetOriginOffset.x;
targetTransform.ty = targetOriginOffset.y;

var cloneData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(targetGlobalBounds.width, targetGlobalBounds.height, true, 0x00000000);
cloneData.draw(target, targetTransform);

var output:Bitmap = new Bitmap(cloneData);
```

**Another update**
So hopefully this will help a little. I was able to recreate what I was doing using Matrix3D.

```
test_mc.response_mc.rotationY = 45;

var matrix:Matrix3D = new Matrix3D();
matrix.prependRotation(45, Vector3D.Y_AXIS);
test2_mc.response_mc.transform.matrix3D = matrix;
test2_mc.response_mc.transform.matrix3D.appendTranslation(0, 0, 0);
```

And I've come closer to getting the bitmap to look correct (thank to a Mike Chambers blog).

```
var mcOffset:Matrix3D = test2_mc.response_mc.transform.matrix3D;
var rawMatrixData:Vector.<Number> = mcOffset.rawData;
var globalBounds:Rectangle = test2_mc.response_mc.getBounds(test2_mc);

var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.a = rawMatrixData[0];
matrix.c = rawMatrixData[1];
matrix.tx = test2_mc.response_mc.x - globalBounds.x;

matrix.b = rawMatrixData[4];
matrix.d = rawMatrixData[5];
matrix.ty = test2_mc.response_mc.y - globalBounds.y;

var bmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(150, test2_mc.height);
test2_mc.response_mc.transform.matrix3D = null;
bmp.draw(test2_mc.response_mc, matrix);
test2_mc.response_mc.transform.matrix3D = mcOffset;

var output:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: Can you provide more details on what isn't working and what is happening?

Is the BitmapData not drawing at all or is it just not the proper angle? Also, you may have to supply a Matrix object to the draw command to get it to draw exactly how you want it.

Comment: Oh sorry. Yes it is that it's not the proper angle. The original image is rotated to where the left is smaller and the right is larger, to look like it's coming at you sort of. When I draw the bitmap, it seems to just rotate it counter-clockwise.

Comment: The easiest way to recreate what I'm doing would to put a movieclip on your stage (instance name test_mc). Next, a movieclip within that (instance name response_mc). Put some text within that movieclip. Use this code:
`test_mc.response_mc.rotationY = 45;
var mc:MovieClip = test_mc;
var bmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(mc.width, mc.height);
bmp.draw(mc);

var output:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmp);
output.x = 270;
output.y = 191;

addChild(output);`

Comment: Oh I see what's going on. Ya, when you rotate an object you actually change it's bounding box. Thus the way you are doing it you would need to offset it a bit when you draw. Try this: `var bounds:Rectangle = mc.response_mc.getBounds(mc);
var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -bounds.x / 2, -bounds.y / 2);` and then when you draw: `bmp.draw(mc, matrix);` I haven't fully tested this yet but it should get you closer.

Comment: Can you explain or provide a link for how each number in the Matrix constructor effects the bitmap? In attempts to adjust to match the original, changing the 0's seems to not makes it not draw for instance and I still can't get the angle right.

Comment: You can check the official AS3 documentation for it here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html

You may need to adjust the default registration point of your symbol and children. But ultimately you are going to need to offset the symbol to be in the right spot since draw goes off the registration point of the rotated symbol for the upper left corner of the bitmap.

Comment: I edited my original post with something else I had originally tried that involved the registration point. I'll keep trying different things, though.

Answer (score 0):

Well I took it a step further back and went to the stage. For whatever reason trying to draw the parent (test_mc) of the rotated movie clip (response_mc) WON'T work, however drawing the stage and setting the bounds to the area of the parent DOES work. Here's my code (which is sadly very simple):

```
var bmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(test_mc.width, test_mc.height);
bmp.draw(stage.getChildAt(0), new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -test_mc.x, -test_mc.y));
var output:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmp);
```